# NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

Tags: java, android, keytool

I wanted to add facebook login feature to my application, so I followed the facebook documentation and I reached the step where I have to provide the development key hash of my app, so I wrote this command in the CMD:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64
```

which did provide the needed key hash but after the key hash, I received the following warning prompting me to migrate to PKCS12

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

so I executed the command in the warning to migrate to PKCS12, but after I did that none of my android projects would run anymore and I receive the following error message during the build:

```
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
```

I found other questions on stackoverflow taking about this error, but none of the solutions worked for me.

from what I read on other questions and forums, HmacPBESHA256 is only available with java 11 and above so I tried to update android studio to the latest version "arctic fox" which has been released recently and allows you to use java 11 but that didn't work too.

any idea what is causing this error? and how could I revert back to whatever format the JKS was previously using?